# How can I solve this as an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to find x such that (A*x).^2 + (B*x).^2 == I  (using Matlab syntax).
A, B are matrices and I is a vector, all with real values.
The number of equations is less than the number of variables, and I can add regularization (for example minimize norm(x) such that the above equation holds).

I tried using cvx (convex optimization SW), but kept getting: Disciplined convex programming error. Isn't this expression convex?

How can x be found?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_x &\quad ||x|| \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad ((Ax)_j)^2 + ((Bx)_j)^2 = I_j &~\forall j=1,\dots,m
\end{aligned}
$$
Your constraints are **non-linear equality** costraints, which makes them non-convex. Hence, CVX cannot help you (directly).

I suggest trying to solve this problem using some variation of a trust-region method. It cannot ensure that you will find a solution, but you have a chance of being close. I cannot explain what it is in one post, so you should Google it. But here is one idea.

Let $f_j(x) = ((Ax)_j)^2 + ((Bx)_j)^2$, and let $g_j(x, y) = f_j(y) + (\nabla f_j(y))^T(x - y)$. As you probably guess, $g_j$ is the first-order Taylor approximation of $f_j$ at $y$. Also, note that $g_j$ is **affine** (linear) in $x$. The idea is the following:

1. Choose some initial guess $x^0$ and trust-region radius $R$.
2. Iteratively, produce a sequence $x^1, x^2, ...$ such that $x^{k+1}$ is the solution of the following optimization problem:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \min_x &\quad ||x|| \\
   \text{s.t.} &\quad g_j(x, x^k) = I_j &~\forall j=1,\dots,m \\
               &\quad ||x - x^k|| \leq R
   \end{aligned}
   $$

You can see that each sub-problem in (2) is convex, since $g_j$ is affine in $x$, and the radius constraint is also convex. So you can use CVX to produce $x^{k+1}$ given $x^k$. However, finding a solution is not ensured and it heavily depends on the choice of $x^0$ and $R$.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I will look into it.